# Parent mask to plane track using clip with vertical aspect ratio

Tags: video, masking, motion-capture

Using Blender 4.0 (and also the beta 4.1), I can make four tracks on a clip, make a plane track from those tracks, and then make a mask parented to that plane track which deforms exactly alongside the plane track.

BUT, I can't seem to make this work if the clip has a vertical aspect ratio (in my case, 1440 x 2880). I've been pulling my hair out, trying to think if there's another place other than the Output properties where I can set the resolution to be vertically oriented for the benefit of either the Motion Tracking or Masking to follow. The resulting mask deformation looks like it's overshooting the tracking plane points on the X axis in a way that suggests there's some kind of hard-coded horizontal aspect ratio at work for either motion tracking or masking, but I can't figure out why that might be.

(Unfortunately, I can't share a screen cap with the footage I'm using to see this, but I can confirm it's happening across several different vertical clips, but not horizontal ones.)